# Filling FaceGrids of Plot3D, with solid color?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, style

I would like to find an easy way to show parts of the bounding box as solid planes.
Given this Plot:
[image: current plot]

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow",
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, Boxed -> False]
```

I would like the bounding box to be displayd like this:
If possible, keep the planes of the bounding box behind the plot dynamically.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`SliceContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html) with `"BackPlanes"` as the slice surface to add face grids with desired colors:

```
ClearAll[addFaceGrids]
addFaceGrids[color_: GrayLevel[.8], linecolor_: White] := Module[{r = PlotRange[#]}, 
   Show[#, SliceContourPlot3D[#, "BackPlanes", 
    {x, r[[1, 1]], r[[1, 2]]}, {y, r[[2, 1]], r[[2, 2]]}, {z, r[[3, 1]], r[[3, 2]]},
     ContourShading -> {color, color}, Contours -> {Automatic, 6}, 
     ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, linecolor], 
     BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, linecolor]] & /@ {x, y, z}]] &
```

**Examples:**

```
addFaceGrids[] @ Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
addFaceGrids[Opacity[.1, Red]] @
 Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Boxed -> False,  BoxRatios -> {3, 2, 1}]
```

[image]

```
addFaceGrids[Opacity[.1, LightBlue]] @
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[3 u], Sin[5 u], u/2}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Tube[.02]}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  Boxed -> False,  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works ! <3

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[canvas]
canvas[color_: GrayLevel[0, .3]] := Graphics3D@{{EdgeForm[], color, EdgeForm[None], 
   InfinitePlane[{Scaled[{0, 0, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1, 0}]}], 
   InfinitePlane[{Scaled[{0, 0, 0}], Scaled[{0, 0, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1, 1}]}], 
   InfinitePlane[{Scaled[{0, 1, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1, 1}], Scaled[{1, 1, 1}]} ]}}

plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
   FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, Boxed -> False];

Show[plot, canvas[], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Show[plot, canvas[Opacity[.3, Orange]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
plot2 = Plot3D[x + Sin[x/2 + (y/2)^2], {x, 4, 6}, {y, 7, 9}, 
   ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
   FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
   Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> {3, 2, 1}];

Show[plot2, canvas[Opacity[.2, Blue]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This a nice idea, unfortunatly it has some disadvantages, for example if one was to change the FaceGridStyle to white, it show that the planes are covering the Grindlines.

Comment: @Tino, you are right about white gridlines. The only way i can think of to get white gridlines  is to add the line primitives.

Comment: ... or have a non-white background.

Comment: @Tino, please see the other answer I posted to get white gridlines.

Answer (score 4):

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
  PlotTheme -> {"Marketing", "NoAxes"}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: `plot /. GrayLevel[x_, y_] :> GrayLevel[0.5, .5]`